# How to fit data with numerical solution of system of parametric ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I need to find the parameters (`k1,k2,k3,k4,k1r,k2r,k3r,k4r`) that fit my data (list of `[Intensity, time]`) using the function `b(t)`, solution of the following system of parametric ODE:

```
{a'[t] == -k1*a[t] - k2*a[t] + k1r*g[t] + k2r*p[t],
 g'[t] == -k1r*g[t] - k3*g[t] + k1*a[t] + k3r*b[t],
 p'[t] == -k4*p[t] - k2r*p[t] + k4r*c[t] + k2*a[t],
 b'[t] == -k3r*b[t] + k3*g[t],
 c'[t] == k4*p[t] - k4r*c[t]}
```

Initial conditions:

```
a[0] == 1,
c[0] == 0,
b[0] == 0,
p[0] == 0,
g[0] == 0,
```

The system of ODE has no analytical solution, so I tried to use `NDSolve`, but it is of course not working because the ODEs are parametric. 
I guess `ParametricNDSolve` would help me, but unfortunately it is not implemented in the version of Mathematica I am using (Mathematica 8). 
Do you have any idea about how to address this problem, avoiding the `ParametricNDSolve` function?

Comment: See Help > Wolfram Documentation > FindFit > Applications > Differential Equations for an example. I will give several MSE links in a followup comment.

Comment: Here are variants of this question, many with responses. I found them using Google and wsearching for (without the quotes) "mathematica stackexchange fit differential". [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29947/how-do-i-find-the-best-fit) [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25018/how-to-adjust-parameters-to-experimental-data-on-a-ndsolve-problem) [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48690/how-do-i-fit-ndsolve-result-to-experimental-data) [4](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39993/fitting-data-using-a-differential-equation)

Comment: More MSE links: [5](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28461/how-to-fit-3-data-sets-to-a-model-of-4-differential-equations) [6](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17941/parametricndsolvevalue-or-ndsolve-fitting) [7](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34807/using-findfit-to-fit-nonlinear-ode-parameters-subject-to-a-constraint-an-inver)

Comment: As far I see, all these examples use ParametricNDSolve, am I right? I would need an alternative method, because I don´t have Mathematica 9. Thanks

Comment: Several of the links I gave provide responses that use `NDSolve` rather than `ParametricNDSolve`.